# Adding Currency Switcher to Nav Menu

Tags: currency, mobile

Been searching around here but can't seem to find an answer to this.
How do I add currency switcher in navigation menu in mobile view? It's displaying on the header in desktop view. Would like to add into navigation menu in mobile view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code where you want to display currency switcher:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>
```